# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jdbc, tomcat7, mysql-connector

I have installed Eclipse Luna recently to do programming on JSP.
Currently i'm trying to connect it with JDBC.
I have downloaded mysql J connector and added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` to the build path.
I've trying running in on my browser and i get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm pretty sure that my settings are correct in terms of setting the path.
I also have set up the CLASSPATH in environment variables just in case that is the main problem, but still i'm facing the same problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is almost never used, you shouldn't try to use it.

Comment: add the jar to the classpath of your application

Answer (score 7):

U need to add jar file to build path

right click on project->build path->configure build path->libraries tab ->add external jar

browse it and add it.

after adding also if u not getting same error, then

You must include the jar file in the Deployment Assembly of the Project.......

```
1)select the web project which contains the jsp file...

 2)select Project tab in the menubar in Eclipse

3)select properties in the drop down menu

4)select Deployment Assembly
```

5)Add your ojdbc6.jar file in it..

Hope this will help u..

Comment: is it needed for maven project too?

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: The adding to the Deployment Assembly was what did the trick, thanks bud! :)

Comment: I have found many answers. This one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your settings are right for building the application, running it needs other settings. You need to place the jar file either in `CATALINA_HOME/lib` or in `<your-app>/WEB-INF/lib` so that the driver is found at run time. The latter is preferable.